# Changing Service Accounts post installation in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I need to change all the service accounts (accounts, not passwords) in a running SharePoint 2013 multi-tier farm, has anyone got documented steps or aware of any article available on the web?

The users were planned right in the beginning, however, due to some unforeseen circumstances we can't continue with those, hence seeking advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve that, following are the steps

1. Registered managed accounts for new users in Central Administration
2. Went to Configure Service Accounts in Central Administration,
   changed users for services.
3. IISRESET
4. Ran Web Application, got yellow screen
   of error.
5. Checked Event Logs, it was crying for application pool's
   account for inadequate permissions.
6. Checked on SQL Server and the account wasn't part of  WSS_Content_Application_Pools membership role on
   CentralAdministration_Content and SharePoint_Config. Granted that
   role to my application pool's identity.

Following link was useful as well
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/russmax/archive/2010/01/08/changing-sharepoint-2010-service-accounts.aspx